# Matrix substraction in Python error or confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I have this code to help understand the problem

```
hypotesisResult = (hypotesis(dataset, theta_init))
print(dataset.T.shape)
print(hypotesisResult.shape)
print(y.shape)
print((hypotesisResult - y).shape)
print(np.subtract(hypotesisResult, y).shape)
```

And the output of this:

> (7, 1329) 
> (1329, 1) 
> (1329,1) 
> (1329, 1329) 
> (1329, 1329)

And my question is, why if a have the matrix "hypotesisResult" with a size of (1329, 1), and i substract "y" (1329,1) from it, it results in a matrix of (1329, 1329) ¿What are i'm doing wrong? I want a new matrix of (1329, 1), this like an scalar substraction

Comment: The result shape suggests that one of the arrays is (1329,) or (1,1329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't trust your displayed shapes.  It might be good to rerun this script, and also check dtype.

Here's the behavior I expect, involving (n,1) and (n,) or (1,n) arrays:

```
In [605]: x=np.ones((4,1),int); y=np.ones((4,),int)
In [606]: x,y
Out[606]: 
(array([[1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1]]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 1]))
In [607]: x-y
Out[607]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [608]: x-y[None,:]
Out[608]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [609]: x-y[:,None]
Out[609]: 
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]])
In [610]: x.T-y
Out[610]: array([[0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The two basic broadcasting rules are:

- add leading size 1 dimensions if needed to match the number of dimensions
- adjust size 1 dimensions to match the other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this isnt your answer but I have something cool for you

consider a matrix saved in a list

```
matx = [[1,54,2],[5,2,3],[2,23,4]]
```

so if we need to calculate its transpose we can use `zip()` fuction

```
print(zip(matx))
```

**results:-**

```
>>>[(1,5,2),(54,2,23),(2,3,4)]
```

Hope you like this